# How to create an invisible mesh like CTRL_Hole in Archimesh?

Tags: boolean-modifier, archimesh-add-on

As far as I understand, to use the boolean modifier to cut a hole, the selected object has to be a mesh. Is it possible to create a mesh that is invisible like CTRL_Hole in Archimesh to create the hole? I've tried to delete the faces of a cube but it doesn't work (there is no hole created when a mesh has no faces).
[image]
Thank you,
Sicong

Answer (score 1):

Select the operand/cutter (the mesh that will add, remove, etc. from the main object).
Set: Object Properties > Viewport Display > Display >  Wire.
This way you see only the edges. And if you really don't wanna see your cutter objects, then in the Outliner, click on the Eye icon (Display in Viewport).

This way you see the result of your stack of Boolean Modifiers, but not the operand(s). Boolean result updates with any modification you make to the geometry of operands in Edit Mode.